# "Linear" package truncating values close to 0 when using `normalize`

Tags: haskell, haskell-linear

I've spent a few minutes debugging a problem that tracked down to "Linear" truncating values that are close to zero when using "Linear.normalize". Specifically, I was taking the cross product of very small triangles and normalizing the result, which, surprisingly, behaved wrongly until I noticed what was wrong and multiplied the cross product by 10000.

Why is that even necessary? How can I get rid of that behavior?

Edit: just for fun, [here is a video of the bug](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GPXRSdsNdEE&feature=youtu.be). Notice that the sphere loses the color when the number of triangles approximating it is big enough? Yes, good luck debugging that...!

Comment: What values were you using?  It could be due to the IEEE floating point format instead of the linear package's math.

Comment: Scratch that, the normalize function uses the `Linear.Epsilon.nearZero` function, it is definitely truncating your values.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear-1.15.5/docs/src/Linear-Metric.html#normalize) for `normalize`, you'll see that it's defined as

```
-- | Normalize a 'Metric' functor to have unit 'norm'. This function
-- does not change the functor if its 'norm' is 0 or 1.
normalize :: (Floating a, Metric f, Epsilon a) => f a -> f a
normalize v = if nearZero l || nearZero (1-l) then v else fmap (/sqrt l) v
  where l = quadrance v
```

What this means is that if the magnitude of your points is really close to 0 you're going to end up with the wrong value.  To avoid this you can write your own `normalize` function without this check as

```
normalize' :: (Floating a, Metric f) => f a -> f a
normalize' v = fmap (/ sqrt l) v where l = quadrance v
```

And with any luck it should solve your problem.

Another way around this might be to scale up your values, perform the computations, then scale them back down, something like

```
normalize' factor = (* factor) . normalize . (/ factor)
```

So you might call

```
normalize' 10e-10 (V3 1e-10 2e-10 3e-10)
```

instead, but this could easily introduce rounding errors due to how IEEE floating point numbers are stored.

**EDIT:** As cchalmers points out this is already implemented as `signorm` in `Linear.Metric`, so use that function instead.

Comment: Your `normalize'` is just `signorm` (also in `Linear.Metric`).

Comment: @cchalmers I'll point that out then, I have no previous experience with the `linear` package, so I'm just going off of reading the source and poking around a bit.

Comment: Interesting, just to make sure - what is exactly the meaning of signorm? Is it doing something else (with the signals, maybe?) or is it exactly just a normalize without truncation?